# How to configure and install Webpack 5 with older Angular version

Tags: angular, webpack

I have two Angular apps: Angular 7 and Angular 16. I would like to connect them using Webpack 5.

I tried to follow the guide at https://www.angulararchitects.io/aktuelles/multi-framework-and-version-micro-frontends-with-module-federation-your-4-steps-guide/.

My idea is to generate the 'dist' folder from the Angular 7 app and create a new project where the 'dist' folder will be included, and then add Webpack 5.

The setup should be similar to the AngularJS sample from the link above: https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angularjs-app.

Do you think I need to do anything special in my Angular 7 version? Will routing work? Does anyone have experience in setting up apps like this? Do you have any other suggestions on how to connect two different versions of Angular?

Comment: Update your project, v7 is 5 years old !

Comment: I am updating with moving one by one feature to Angular 16. It is no easy to do it as is.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you bring up webpack specifically. One of the main selling points for using angular is that the framework with the cli abstracts away most webpack-specific concerns. There is an upgrade guide and as long as you haven't been doing anything excessively fancy, the upgrade process is somewhat trivial. Also, what's the deal with bringing up AngularJS? if you're working with anything v2+, you shouldn't be touching anything from AngularJS.